# In Magento, how can I preview a page before saving it?

Tags: content-management-system, magento

I am using the Magento ver. 1.4.0.1 Community Edition. The problem I am running into is that Magento only allows me to preview pages that I have already saved. This works fine if I am creating a new page - but what if I am editing a current page? I want to be sure that the changes I make look good on the site before saving them.

Does anyone know of a way to preview a static cms page before saving the changes made? I'm open to using some sort of plugin if anyone knows of one.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there isn't one in Magento, you'll just have to save it and view it.

A lot of the work I've done in Magento has been done on a development server, once everything was set it got moved to the production server. I'm not saying you need two servers, but having at least a development instance of Magento will help when editing a live site.

Comment: Sweet that's what I thought, but it's nice to have some confirmation.

Answer (score 1):

for non-trivial changes, I normally create a new page with a URL that's not linked anywhere and then load that up to preview, before copying the content/settings to the real page.

Comment: That works better than having a separate dev environment. Thanks for the tip!